# YUI: Stop event handlers from triggering while an animation is running

Tags: javascript, yui

So I'm using YUI to add some animations in my application triggered when a user clicks certain elements. However, I'm running into a common problem that is easily fixed with some poor coding, but I'm looking for a more elegant solution that's less error-prone.

Often, when the user clicks something, a DOM element is animated (using Y.Anim) and I subscribe to that animation's 'end' event to remove the element from the document after its animation has completed. Pretty standard stuff.

However, problems arise when the user decides to spam-click the element that triggers this event. If the element is going to be removed from the DOM when the animation ends, and the user triggers an event handler that fires off ANOTHER animation on the same element, this 2nd animation will eventually cause YUI to spit really nasty errors because the node it was animating on suddenly disappeared from the document. The quickest solution I've found for this is to just set some module/class-level boolean state like 'this.postAnimating' or something, and inside the event handler that triggers the animation, check if this is set to true, and if so, don't do anything. In the 'end' handler for the animation, set this state to false.

This solution is really, really not ideal for many reasons. Another possible solution is to detach the event handler for duration of the animation and re-attach it once the animation is complete. This is definitely a little better, but I still don't like having to do extra bookkeeping that I could easily forget to do if forgetting to do so leads to incomprehensible YUI errors.

What's an elegant and robust way to solve this problem without mucking up a multi-thousand-line Javascript file with bits and pieces of state?

Here's some example code describing the issue and my solution to it.

```
var popupShowing = false,
    someElement  = Y.one('...');

someElement.on("click", showPopUp)

var showPopup = function(e) {
    if(!popupShowing) {
      popupShowing = true;
      var a = new Y.Anim({
          node: someElement,
          duration: 0.2,
          ...
      });

      a.on('end', function() {
          someElement.remove(true);
          popupShowing = false;
      });

      a.run();
    }
}
```

So if the user clicks "someElement" many times, only one animation will fire. If I didn't use popupShowing as a guard, many animations on the same node would be fired if the user clicked quickly enough, but the subsequent ones would error out because someElement was removed when the first completed.

Comment: Asking YUI questions is best done in the forum on yuilibrary.com, since the developers themselves are there and often answer such questions. Why don't you just stop the currently running animation before starting a new one?

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have some piece of example code by any chance? I can't imagine where the problem lies, really... :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I might go there and see what advice they have. Also, I can't stop the animation, because only the first one should trigger. I'll add some example code, though.

Comment: Yeah, but I'd think they might ask for a code example too :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** By popular demand, a YUI way:

```
myAnim.get('running')
```

tells you whether an animation is running. To use this you might have to restructure the way you call the event so the animation is in the right scope, for example:

```
YUI().use('anim', function (Y) {
   var someElement = Y.one('...');
   var a = new Y.Anim({
       node: someElement,
       duration: 0.2,
       ...
   });

   a.on('end', function() {
       someElement.remove(true);
   });

   someElement.on('click', function() {
       if (!a.get('running')) {
           a.run();
       }
   });
});
```

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/nwellcome/umzvf/)

**Previously I had said:** I personally like the way jQuery handles this. In jQuery, each element has a queue for animation functions. During animations an "in progress" sentinel is pushed to the front for the duration of the animation so anything that doesn't want to step on an animation peeks at the front of the queue for "in progress" and decides what to do from there, e.g. do nothing, get in line, preempt the current animation, etc.

<strike>I don't know enough about YUI to tell you how to implement this, but</strike> I find it to be a very elegant solution.

Comment: This is not an "answer", but a "comment" at most. Even the subject of the quesiton says "YUI" - and YUI3 is a MUCH better lib for app development than jQuery, which is very good - YUI(3) has a different PURPOSE. So please accept when people use something else than you do.

Comment: I didn't say "you should use jQuery", I said "this is how another library solves this problem, maybe you could use a similar solution".

Comment: And I said he asked SPECIFICALLY about YUI. You answered a question that wasn't asked, which means it's just noise, period.

Comment: I've added a YUI solution, is this better now?

Comment: hm, I like this a lot more even though it seems to be the same idea. It's much clearer because you're tying the logic specifically to the animation, not some nebulous global state. I doubt I can get more tightly integrated into the library than this, but it'd be nice to see.

Comment: I just realized that my if statement to check 'running' is superfluous. YUI doesn't let you .run() an Anim while it is already running. What I did to solve the problem was just to define the animation outside of the onclick function.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Transition API.  It's more concise, and may very well do what you want out of the box.

```
someElement.transition({ opacity: 0, duration: 0.2 }, function () { this.remove(); });
// OR
someElement.on('click', function () { this.hide(true, { duration: 0.2 }); });
// OR
someElement.on('click', someElement.hide);
```

Personally, I haven't used Anim since Transition was added in 3.2.0.  Transition uses CSS3 where supported (with hardware acceleration), and falls back to a JS timer for older browsers.
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/examples/transition/transition-view.html

Answer (score 0):

Quick & dirty solution to this particular issue?

Attach your handlers using [.once](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/YUI.html#method_once)() instead

```
someElement.once("click", showPopUp)
```

Also suitable if you need the handler re-attached later, just call that line again when the animation is done. You could also store your state information on the node itself using [setData](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/Node.html#method_setData)/[getData](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/Node.html#method_getData) but that is just a panacea to the real problem of state tracking.

Also, +1 to Luke's suggestion to use Transition for DOM property animation, it's grand.